# Passing data between components

Tags: angular

I've got a problem with passing data between components. 
I've got a paraent and child components. I pass data using via @Input.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'parent'
})
export class Parent implements OnInit {
  obj: any;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataService.getJson('this.apiUrl').subsribe(res=> this.obj = res);
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'child'
})
export class Child implements OnInit {
  @Input passedObj: any;
  obj: any;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.obj=this.passedObj;
  }
}
```

And than I'm passing data this way:

```html
<child [passedObj]="obj"></child>
```

And the problem is, that data arrive too late. The view of child component is rendered quicker.
How to solve this problem?

Comment: Why are you doing `this.obj=this.passedObj;` instead of just using `this.passedObj`?

Comment: Replace `@Input` with `@Input()`.

Comment: try it in `ngAfterViewInit()`

Comment: @user184994 thank you I didn't even know that I can use Input directly.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to pass data between angular components. You can find one of my medium articles cased on that in [here](https://medium.com/@chameeradulanga87/sharing-data-between-angular-components-f76fa680bf76). It contains example codes as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this 
assign some default value to obj like `null` or `undefined` or something else when obj having value `child` will render in dom.

```
<child [passedObj]="obj" *ngIf="obj"></child>
```